# Create elevation profile using Java

Tags: java, swing, draw, elevation

I need to draw a elevation profile, something similar with [Elevation Profile from Google Earth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0Jsv.png).

I know the latitude, longitude, elevation and distance, but I don't know how I need to make this profile.

Comment: Your best bet is to use a graphing package, like JFreeChart.  If you want to create the graph yourself using Java Swing, you'll need to extend a JPanel and draw.  Start by creating the X and Y axis.  Once you have that working, create the plotline,  Finally, color under the plotline.

Comment: **"**_I know the latitude, longitude, elevation and distance_**"** for a profile you need the height at every point along the "distance".